# Python drop duplicated pairs only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, data-cleaning

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
Time                        X     Y
2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.634508  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.634508  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.943522  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.943522  200   10.1
```

I would like to remove duplicated PAIRS only. i.e. The first pair and second pair of .565333 timestamps are actually unique, but doing something like `t[~t.duplicated()]` will remove all the duplicates like this:

```
2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.634508  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.943522  200   10.1
```

whereas instead I want this:

```
2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.634508  200   10.1
2023-02-01T15:03:02.943522  200   10.1
```

Comment: Are you opposed to walking through the dataframe manually to determine pairs? Are they always back to back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First de-duplicate using [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) combined with floor division ([`floordiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.floordiv.html)) by the number of rows to group, then you will be able to [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) while maintaining the first row of each group:

```
N = 2
cols = ['Time', 'X', 'Y']
(df.assign(n=df.groupby(cols).cumcount().floordiv(N))
   .drop_duplicates(subset=cols+['n'])
)
```

*NB. you can use any `N` value to work on higher group sizes, for example `N=3` to work with triplets of rows. Also, `cols` defines the columns to use to identify the duplicates. I assumed you want to use all columns, but you can use only a subset of them if needed.*

Output:

```
                         Time    X     Y  n
0  2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200  10.1  0
2  2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200  10.1  1  # second pair
4  2023-02-01T15:03:02.634508  200  10.1  0
6  2023-02-01T15:03:02.943522  200  10.1  0
```

Intermediate before `drop_duplicates`:

```
                         Time    X     Y  n
0  2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200  10.1  0
1  2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200  10.1  0  # duplicated
2  2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200  10.1  1
3  2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333  200  10.1  1  # duplicated
4  2023-02-01T15:03:02.634508  200  10.1  0
5  2023-02-01T15:03:02.634508  200  10.1  0  # duplicated
6  2023-02-01T15:03:02.943522  200  10.1  0
7  2023-02-01T15:03:02.943522  200  10.1  0  # duplicated
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the duplicated method with the **subset** parameter to specify the columns to consider for identifying duplicates. In this case, you want to consider duplicates only based on the pairs of `Time` and `(X, Y)` values. Maybe it help you:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time': ['2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333', '2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333',
             '2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333', '2023-02-01T15:03:02.565333',
             '2023-02-01T15:03:02.634508', '2023-02-01T15:03:02.634508',
             '2023-02-01T15:03:02.943522', '2023-02-01T15:03:02.943522'],
    'X': [200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
    'Y': [10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1]
})

# Identify duplicates based on Time and (X,Y) pairs
duplicates = df.duplicated(subset=['Time', 'X', 'Y'])

# Invert boolean mask to select non-duplicates
non_duplicates = ~duplicates

# Print non-duplicates
print(df[non_duplicates])
```

Comment: This won't yield the expected output